# Uninstall weave docker

Tags: docker, weave

There is a nice guide how to install weave [here](https://www.weave.works/), but i can't find anywhere how to uninstall it properly. Just removing containers doesn't help because weave changes network configuration.

Comment: Did you try to `weave stop` ? Do you mean `uninstall` or `stop`? weave is deploy through image, if you want to remove an image it is then `docker rmi image-id`.

Comment: Yep, I used `weave stop` but it just stops container. However network configuration on host doesn't change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`weave reset` will undo the network config